# Databricks spark.read csv has row #torefresh

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, databricks

I am going to read csv to dataframe 
1. I create the structure 
2. load csv spark.read.option("header", "false").schema(schema).option('delimiter', ',').option('mode', 'PERMISSIVE').csv(path1)   < path1 is an array having about 10000 csv 
and I get the df like in the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAv8k.jpg)

how to check which files/ which rows getting the #torefresh and null...…???

Answer (score 0):

To know which files contains those rows you can use `input_file_name` function from `pyspark.sql.functions`

e.g.

```
df.where("col1 == '#torefresh'").withColumn("file", input_file_name()).show()
```

with that you can easily also get an aggregate with one row per file

```
df.where("col1 == '#torefresh'").withColumn("file", input_file_name()).groupBy("file").count().show()

+--------------------+-----+
|                file|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|file:///C:/Users/...|  119|
|file:///C:/Users/...|  131|
|file:///C:/Users/...|  118|
|file:///C:/Users/...|  127|
|file:///C:/Users/...|  125|
|file:///C:/Users/...|  116|
+--------------------+-----+
```

I don't know of a good spark way to find row number in original file - the moment you load csv into a DataFrame this information is pretty much lost. There is a `row_number` function but it works over a window so the numbers will depend on the way you define window partitioning / sorting.

If you are working with a local file system, you could try to manually read the csv again and find row numbers, something like this:

```
import csv
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

@udf(returnType=ArrayType(StringType()))
def getMatchingRows(filePath):
    with open(filePath.replace("file:///", ""), 'r') as file:
      reader = csv.reader(file)
      matchingRows = [index for index, line in enumerate(reader) if line[0] == "#torefresh"]
      return matchingRows

withRowNumbers = df.where("col1 == '#torefresh'")\
    .withColumn("file", input_file_name())\
    .groupBy("file")\
    .count()\
    .withColumn("rows", getMatchingRows("file"))
withRowNumbers.show()

+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|                file|count|                rows|
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
|file:///C:/Users/...|  119|[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1...|
|file:///C:/Users/...|  131|[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1...|
|file:///C:/Users/...|  118|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7...|
|file:///C:/Users/...|  127|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7...|
|file:///C:/Users/...|  125|[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7...|
|file:///C:/Users/...|  116|[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8...|
+--------------------+-----+--------------------+
```

But it's going to be pretty inefficient and if you expect to have those rows in many of the files it beats the point of using DataFrames. I'd suggest working on the source of data and enabling some sort of Ids on creation, but that's of course unless all you need to know is that file contains any.

If besides knowing that first value is "#torefresh" you also need all other values to be null you can extend the `where` filter and the manual check in udf.